# Is there a way to render ContentPages under the top ContentPage in the navigation stack?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin.Forms app and I'm using a `NavigationPage` to hold a stack of `ContentPages`. The navigation makes sense to me, but I'd like to somehow be able to render the `ContentPages` underneath the top `ContentPage`. Specifically, I'd like a transparent background on one that lets some of the page underneath be visible. I know that I could use the popup classes, but they just use the underlying dialog architecture which leaves a lot to be desired, especially on Android.

If this cannot be done natively with something like a simple switch that I've missed, is there any way to create my own `NavigationPage` class that implements the behavior I'm after? What about any tutorials that would walk me through this process?

Comment: the pages are "stacked" conceptually, but they aren't actually rendered that way.

Comment: The documentation isn't super clear on this, and I'm aware that this isn't the default implementation. But this is my requirement, and I know it's doable natively, so I'm asking if there's a way to do it with Forms.

Comment: Do you have any references on how to do it natively?  If so you could use that as a basis for a custom rendere

Comment: I've done it on Android using Activities, but I was hoping to avoid doing it myself unless I needed to. Thus the question. Sounds like that might be the only solution, though. Do you have any documentation to support your comment that ContentPages are only stacked conceptually? It seems strange that they would go through the trouble to document it that way if that wasn't actually the case. Just want to expand my own knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As [microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/pages) says

> A Page object represents a ViewController in iOS and a Page in the
> Universal Windows Platform. On Android, each page takes up the screen
> like an Activity, but Xamarin.Forms pages are not Activity objects.

On the Android platform, the PageRenderer class instantiates a ViewGroup control.
If you want to display multiple pages, Carousel Page can do the job https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page

To use popup, you can download [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).Here are my sample code.

popuppage:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:pages="http://rotorgames.com"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"  
             x:Class="MyFormsApp.Views.MyPage1">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Hello World!" FontSize="Large"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**open popup over mainpage:**

```
  public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new MyPage1(), true);
        }
```

result:

[image]

edit:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <ContentView
            BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="10,0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Opacity="0.5"
            x:Name="myContentview">

            <StackLayout  HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400">
                <Label Text="This is a popup" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            
        </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I want to display multiple pages on top of one another, not one at a time by swiping through them. This does not solve my problem, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I am afraid that you will use popup

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect an implementation of that?

Comment: check the update above.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Is there no native implementation I can use? I'd rather not rely on a 3rd party solution if possible. Also, I've seen this NuGet package referenced multiple times before, making me think this question and answer is getting close to duplicate territory if not.

Comment: As I know, there are only three types popup in native forms popup, to customize it, you can try absolutelayout with conetentview to achieve it.